# How to add the textformfield value to the list without button click

Tags: flutter

```
TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value){
                  currentoption = value;
                  alloptions.add(currentoption.toString());
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "  Enter Option",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I am trying to save the input text to store in the list if it completes the typying but is i am printing the value of alloptions list it prints the character by character value how the word is typed.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to call the `setState` function within the `onChanged` callback?

Comment: no like i am tyyping "prince" the array is like [p, pr, pri, prin, princ, prince]

Answer (score 0):

it's because every time you typing in textfield It will trigger onChange: and in your onChange: use variable.add(value.toString) It's mean every time you typing in textfield it will add new text after old text

Comment: can you tell me how to acheive that

Comment: if yes you can do a simple solution like print alloption[alloption.length-1] but it's gonna be low efficiency solution btw